# Product Landing Page test suite problems: video and sticky navbar elements Free Code Camp

Tags: html, css, mocha.js, bdd, chai

I'm trying to pass the last few items on the FCC test suite before I submit my responsive project and I have two that I'm getting errors on when I should not-  I understand test suites much better than before, but can't figure these two out.

6. I can watch an embedded product video with id="video".
   AssertionError: #video should be an  or  element

   - The #video element IS a video so I'm not sure why this is still catching.

```html
<video id="video" autoplay loop src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mpauldesigns/video/upload/v1532013100/photo_collage.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <p>Your browser doesn't support mp4 video</p>
</video>
```

1. The navbar should always be at the top of the viewport.
   AssertionError: #header or one of its children should be at the top of the viewport even after scrolling: expected 299.9624938964844 to be close to 0 +/- 15

   - I made sure the navbar is a child of the header, is sticky, and right near the top so I don't know where it's pulling 300 from!

Here's my project:
https://codepen.io/mpauldesigns/pen/LrqBOQ

What am I missing? Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

you can use video

```html
<iframe id="video"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RDNw8KC0j_M" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

and secound thing
In the header, you can add a position at fixed

```
#header{
position:fixed;
top:0px;}
```